# Can I store/ retrieve multiple passwords in the iOS keychain for a single user?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, authentication, keychain

Am I understanding the keychain documentation correctly? My application can store many key/value pairs for a single user of my application within the keychain, and ultimately retrieve those values in **clear text** - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You sure can. Check out this example gist

https://gist.github.com/ndfred/775896

Comment: Nice! Thank you for sharing. Is it possible to encrypt the values too?

Comment: The keychain encrypts those values for you. If you have the option, I would suggest using one of the many "keychain wrappers"

https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess